# Example of a non-quasiconvex function which is quasiconvex at a point

Tags: convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I have found examples of non-convex functions which are convex at some points.

The function
$$f(x) \mapsto 
\begin{cases} 
      x^2 & x < 1 \\
      1 & x \geq 1
   \end{cases}
$$
is non-convex, but is convex for $x\leq-1$.

So far I have not been able to find non-quasiconvex funtions which are quasiconvex at some/a point(s).

By quasiconvexity at a point I understand this:

A function $f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R}$ is quasiconvex at $\mathbf{x'} \in \mathcal{X}$ if 
$$f(\lambda \mathbf{x'} + (1- \lambda)\mathbf{x}) \leq \max\{f(\mathbf{x'}) , f(\mathbf{x})\}$$
for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}.$

Comment: You should not speak of a function being convex at a point; rather a function may be convex on an interval. That just means that all of the chords of the graph nowhere go below the graph. If you're talking about "at a point", then where are the chords?

Comment: For convexity at a point, one of the ends of the chord is fixed at that point. This is how it is defined by Bazaraa in Nonlinear Programming  - Theory and Algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an example I think.

The function
$$f(x) \mapsto \min \{1-\sqrt{\lvert x \rvert}, 0\}$$
is nonquasiconvex but is quasiconvex at points $\lvert x \rvert \leq 1$.